# Disabling TLS 1.0 and 1.1 on Windows

Tags: windows, ssl

I was disabling TLS 1.0 and 1.1 (finally) which worked wonderfully for all but one user. When this user tries to connect to an SQLExpress server it forces her to use TLS 1.0 and refuses 1.2 if I or any other user attempts the same connection the communication is in TLS 1.2 with no problems.

This users computer is running Windows 20h2 and the server is running windows Server 2016 Datacenter.

Comment: What is the SQL Server version, and what are they using to connect?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, the client negotiates which version the server and client will use. This is just an assumption but it seems that the client may not support tls.1.2 as other are able to connect and only this one user cannot, by default windows should support TLS 1.2 though.

Are all the clients windows 10 20h2 ?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways in which you can disable TLS 1.0 and 1.1
You can either use IISCrypto which is a program that makes disabling and enabling TLS (and other things) very easy, or you can do this via the registry keys (which if they don't exist you can create)

Try disabling the 1.0 and 1.1 on the server itself as well :)

Here's a link with the explanations:
[Disable TLS](https://support.solarwinds.com/SuccessCenter/s/article/Disable-TLS-1-0-or-1-1-in-the-registry-or-using-IIS-Crypto-in-the-Dameware-server?language=en_US)